# Contains<>() not returning true on match

Tags: c#, string, contains

I have a string

```
String input = "nbfs;jlt;\"";
```

With this string I use .Contains<>()

```
if (input.Contains<String>("nbfs;jlt;"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("True");
}
```

also

```
 if (input.Contains("nbfs;jlt;"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True");
    }
```

does not work.
Why does the above if statement return false?

Comment: It might be because the string you are looking for doesn't exist in the input string...

Comment: Have you tried to compile this code?

Comment: @Charleh Sorry it was a typo when writing the question corrected.

Comment: @L.B Yes the code Compiles

Comment: @Jordon, I've up voted to cancel out the downvotes although I wouldn't of normally. Pay attention to what you post next time.

Comment: I doubt it returns either true *or* false, considering it won't even compile.  String doesn't contain a definition for `.Contains<>`

Comment: [Compilation Error](http://ideone.com/LPt9Zu) - Maybe you have some extension method defined somewhere?

Comment: This should work...I just tested (after removing the <String> part

Comment: @MikeChristensen I have no extension methods installed

Comment: @JordanTrainor - In that case I don't know what `String.Contains<>` is.  I'm very surprised the code you posted compiles for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input.Contains<String>("nbfs;jlt;")` is expecting an enumeration of strings.

use: `input.Contains("nbfs;jlt;")`

**EDIT**
In response to the many comments, the `.Contains<T>` method will not compile on a standard string:

```
string input = "nbfs;jlt;";
input.Contains<String>("nbfs;jlt;") // this will never compile
```

The `.Contains<T>` method is expecting some type of enumerable input such as the following to compile:

```
input.Select( x => x.ToString() ).Contains<String>( "nbfs;jlt;" )
```

Given that the OP is saying the code compiles, I would suggest opening a new Console Project and start from scratch. And type everything, do not copy/paste.

On a side note: There may be some odd entity characters hidden when you copy/paste from files, so that may be one reason why the Contains method will not work on your string.

**Edit 2**
This will compile and return true based on your sample strings. Copy/Paste this into a console app and be sure not to include any assemblies other than the default ones with the Console app:

```
string input = "nbfs;jlt;\"";

bool isContained = input.Contains( "nbfs;jlt;" );

Console.WriteLine( isContained );
```

Comment: OK ill rewrite this in a new project then reply back here with the outcome.

Comment: OK rewrote it without copy + paste and still returns false

Comment: See Edit 2 - the sample will return true.

Comment: OK Edit 2 works in a normal console application but in my app it doesn't work but the following works in my code and returns true 
                    if ("nbfs;jlt;\"".Contains("nbfs;jlt;"))
                    {
                    }
                    but if(input.Contains("nbfs;jlt;")) returns false even though input is exactly the same as the first if statment

Comment: for some reason has started working in my normal console app maybe just a glitch?

Comment: Gremlin? Glitch? Ghost? Goblin? Ghoul? Sounds ghastly to me... eeGaaads!

Answer (score 2):

This will not compile with `.Contains<String>` unless you have some sort of extension method you are using? Is this possibly a custom class you are unaware of?

You should just use string's built in contains `input.Contains("string");`

Comment: `Remove the semicolon and itll work` I won't work, since it is not compilable.

Comment: With the OPs edit, this isnt correct anymore, but I was talking about in the string he was checking against in the contains

Comment: its checking `nbfs;jlt;"` for `nbfs;jlt;`. Shouldn't the contains function return true in that case?

Comment: @L.B It does compile and run fine. it just doesn't output true

Comment: `With the OPs edit, this isnt correct anymore`, it wasn't correct in its original version too.

Comment: @L.B A moot point now, but I think you are just confusing what my point was

Comment: @L.B at the end of the contains, yes. I am guessing maybe you were talking about the fact that contains isnt a generic. To that, yes I noticed the glaring mistake and glazed over the contains mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `<String>` and use: `if (input.Contains("nbfs;jlt;"))`

Comment: Strange - it works for me and returns `true`... If it's a part of bigger code, check it with debugger if the `input` has the value you expect it should.

Comment: iv tested with a slimmed down version of my code and debugged line by line and it still skips over the if statement even though it should be true

Answer (score 0):

[String.Contains isn't a generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx), so you don't need to specify a type parameter.

Try this instead.

```
if (input.Contains("nbfs;jlt;"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("True");
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't return true